# How do I clean indexes in google app engine java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I read from docs that this can be done by

```
./appengine-java-sdk/bin/appcfg.sh vacuum_indexes myapp/war
```

But when I run it I get a error message saying "Can't open file". I tried running appcfg.cmd instead but then I get a classNotFoundException. Anyone know why this is?

I can't use any command with appcfg at all. Here's a screenshot of what happens:

[image]

Comment: From error it's not very clear. But are your other commands with appcfg working fine? That will confirm it is able to identify directory and classes properly.

Comment: I have updated my question. Hopefully it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appcfg.sh looks for `appengine-tools-api.jar`  which has class  `com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg` . If you look the sh file in a text editor, you will notice that by default it looks in lib directory which is in parent of current directory (Unless you have changed it). So does your "New javakod" directory has a lib directory and does it have the jar file mentioned above? Or just edit the shell file to pick up the jar file from classpath and make sure you add the jar file to your classpath.

The reason for your first error is the same, it's not able to locate the index xml file at location where it is looking for.

Comment: Alright, I corrected that mistake and placed the whole appengine-java-sdk-1.5.3 in my Web2Test folder. When I ran appcfg.sh vacuum_indexes war I still got the error saying "can't open file appcfg.sh". But when I ran appcfg.cmd vacuum_indexes war I did not get any error. I did not get any message saying it worked either. Nothing happened. Looking at my dashboard, the index with the error is still there. Any idea?

Comment: .sh file won't run, as you are in Windows environment. appcfg.cmd is what you would need to use. I suggest just run "appcfg.cmd" this will print the help which will show various options and action combinations you should provide and then execute with all appropriate parameters set. Post again when you have some more data/error